# "Critic" badge without downvote?

Tags: bug

I received the "Critic" badge for my first downvote on Main, but I am quite sure I haven't downvoted any posts yet. Glitch in the system?

Comment: Bugs like these go to the mother meta. BTW, if you've downvoted a post and [removed it quickly within the grace period, you'll get the critic badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2137/205334) while your profile shows 0 downs ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ: that should have been an answer....

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ No, it's perfectly fine to post bugs on per-site metas, you don't have to go to MSO for that.

Comment: @MadScientist: I don't say it's *wrong* here. But, it's best on MSO because a lot of guys would have a look at the issue and it's not a *Physics.SE-only* related problem. It may (or may not) have happened already in many other sites ;-)

Comment: @userØØ7: Yeah... But, this is just a meta. So, I thought I could give a quick rush reply and finally fall sleep. Moreover, I'm not sure if it solves the issue ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ: No one can give a full and final answer to such a question. Answer would be wild guess the best guess would be the correct answer, or otherwise finally question becomes a mystery question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you've downvoted a post and removed it quickly within the grace period/ removed it after the post was improved, you'll get the critic badge for clicking that down button:

[image]

while your profile shows 0 downs .

Badges are never removed once awarded,so your [`critic`] badge doesn't go away.

Comment: It's possible that I did inadvertently click on the down arrow and immediately reversed that, though I don't recall. However, the explanation given by Crazy Buddy and you seems plausible.

Comment: I confirm the answer, from experimental evidence.